# Anyway to accept kwarg with random CaMElCase?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm writing some classes which rely heavily on **kwargs. I am wanting to write it in a manner that end users can create these objects without having to know the exact case of the keyword.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # Rewrite this to accept random case
        if "EnableDebug" in kwargs and kwargs.get("EnableDebug") == True:
            print "EnableDebug mode."
```

And then end-user of this library could do something this:

```
myobj = Foo(enableDEBUG=True)
```

I know I can brute force thru **kwargs and run thru a bunch of tests and string manipulation but was curious of there was a nifty trick or something I'm not aware of.

Thx for any help

***Update***

I'm getting an error when I try this using python 2.76:

```
File "/home/devel/test.py", line 144, in <dictcomp>
    kwargs = {k.lower():v for k,v in kwargs}
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a number of ways to do this, but you could just standardize the args to lowercase and then do whatever testing you want to do:

```
kwargs = {k.lower():v for k,v in kwargs.items()}
```

Then all of your strings are guaranteed to be standardized.

Comment: As usual, I forgot to do `kwargs.items()` rather than just `kwargs`. It's edited to reflect the correct call now.